# Android: Build SDK?

Tags: android

I'm building an Android app, I'm a newbie and I was wondering what build SDK and Minimum required SDK is recommended?

Also what does each one mean?

Comment: developer.android.com   & 2.3 is the most used version right now keep that as minimum &  best of luck

Comment: But what build sdk should i use?

Comment: Usually people set minimum sdk to Android 2.2 (this option covers most of current devices). Build sdk should be the same as the platform sdk for which you're developing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upto my knowledge build SDK means which Android O.S version you are building against and

Minimum required SDK means: the minimum Android O.S version you want to support.

For Example

If build SDK = 2.3.3

and Minimum required SDK = 2.2

then your application will run on 2.2 and above